# The Crosswalk framework for Android

Tags: android, html, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I have a few questions about Crosswalk, I tried searching on Google, but since I don't know the exact names of some functions, I can't find anything.

1. Is it possible to use Crosswalk to render a **online** website?
2. If the answer to question 1 is no, Is it possible to write a HTML5+JS app, that renders an iframe, with in there a online site?

If question 1 is yes, can you post a link to a documentation or a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do both action.
here is some [help](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html) on the official web site. and here is a code that might work for you too

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("xwl");
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        XWalkView view = new XWalkView(this, this);
        logger.severe("loadeding ...");
        view.load("https://www.google.com", null);
        logger.severe("loaded");
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest file

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.wxl"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                 android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The two permissions are needed.

The only problem I found is that it renders blurry :( on android. 
Good luck.